# How to migrate entire Eclipse workspace to Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, ant, android-gradle-plugin

I have an **Eclipse** workspace which contains 60 projects. 40 of the projects are **Android library projects** and some library projects uses other library projects. Relations between projects are very complicated however with **eclipse's library system** it was really easy to manage them. It seems **Android Studio** has is fairly complicated system when it comes to work with multiple projects.

Here is my main dilemma, should I create one big **Android Studio project**  and port entire **Eclipse workspace** into it as **modules** or should I create new **Android Studio projects** for every single **Eclipse Project**.

**IntelliJ** explains that **IntelliJ (AS) 'Project'** is equivalent of **Eclipse workspace**, with this logic creating one big **Android Studio project** seems better option however I have read that doing things in Android Studio's way is to keep projects separated.

As you see I am really confused and I don't want to jump in work before convincing myself about the best solutiın. I have spent 2 days and haven't find a satisfying answer yet. Please share your ideas with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's possible to make a really HUGE project with several modules.

In my last job I had the project with modules like app for Tablet, app for smartphone, another app which takes similar resources and libraries and also has separated tablet and smartphone version.

If I were you I would import to Android Studio every made before in Eclipse `library` first, then make them ready to implement to your existing projects.

Next, if I had been imported libraries I would try to import every project of  my 20 existing apps and add to its `build.gradle` these libraries.

Yes, it would be a lot of work to import as huge workspace to Android Studio, and might it seems to be easier to create one enourmous project than split it to several apps using existing libraries.

But like I said don't do one project with several modules. It would may cause in slow Gradle building, taking too much computer resources, changing one library may cause problem in some modules It's also harder to write automated tests or unit tests.

Do import libraries first and make them executable and then, finally import your existing apps and connect them with your libraries. I'm sure it would give you a profit in the nearest future